# Using Python (Pandas) groupby and datetime to sum values in the morning and afternoon for different markets

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot, pandas-groupby, pandas-resample

I have a datetime column that looks like the following:

[image: DELIVERY_DUE_BY_CUSTOM_REFERENCE]

And a "market" column that has sting values such as ['NYC', LA', 'HOU', etc.] I also have a column "ID" that has random Order IDs. I am trying to look at each market by day (data goes back 5 months) and count the number of IDs that occur before noon and the number that occur after noon. My first step was to groupby market and date, but I don't know how to 1) break up date into day and hour (so I can group it further) or 2) shortcut that and find a way to just count Order IDs for everyday before noon and after noon (will need two new columns)

My attempt is below... the issue is that it's keeping the hhmmss on the date column.

[image: Attempt to group by day]

I've also tried to resample by D and H, but that isn't doing the trick for me yet...
[image: Attempt to resample]

Can anyone help me groupby market and day, then count Order IDs that occur before noon in one field and after noon in a second field?

Comment: Create an hour column using `df['date'].dt.hour`

Comment: I use this to get a numerical value for hour -> `output_df['hour'] = pd.Categorical(output_df['DELIVERY_DUE_BY_CUSTOM_REFERENCE'].dt.hour, categories=range(24))`, but I am still struggling to sum by hour for a given day

Comment: Map them to morning and afternoon then use that as one of your groupby keys

Comment: Okay, before that step, how can I group by day? Do I need to split my datetime column to remove hhmmss?

Comment: Create a column using `df['date'].dt.floor('D')`

Comment: is the datetime field normalized to utc or are you also dealing with time zone differences and does it matter?

Comment: normalized to utc